# How can I open ubuntu desktop from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot

Is there any command I have to write in ubuntu lts to open the gui?
Note: I have installed ubuntu desktop. 
I just don't know how to open it.

Comment: I must say, at first I had no clue what you were asking, but desktop gui is not opening, right?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it? Did you go trough installation guide with gui?

If yes, there is a chance you coincidentally switched to virtual console by using `Ctrl+Alt+Fn`. The GUI runs with X server and you can switch back to it by using `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Alt+F2`.

Comment: Well actually at first I installed ubuntu LTS 18.04 terminal app, then I installed ubuntu-desktop by typing a command in terminal. Cu